# Rails/PostgreSQL - Locking rows based on attribute?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, locking

I have a `generate` method in one of my controllers that creates, updates and possibly destroys some `ListColumns` and `ListCells`, both of which have a `list_id` that points back to the original `List`. I need to ensure that the ListColumns won't change while I'm creating the ListCells.

However, since generating the data might take a while, if a separate user calls `generate` on a different list, I'd like it to go ahead and create the ListColumns and ListCells for that list.

So, is there a way to lock the table so that I can't add a ListColumn with a particular `list_id` until after the transaction is completed?

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `list` table rows themselves as locks. Simply select a row from `list` in exclusive mode:

```
select list.list_id from list where list.list_id = ? for update
```

Even if you're not going to actually update that row, doing that at the start of your method will block any other executions with the same `list_id`

Comment: @Topher: BTW, AR has a [`lock!`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Locking/Pessimistic.html#method-i-lock-21) method that does a `select ... for update`.

Comment: @muistooshort - Indeed, I found that in my searching and it's what I'm using. Thanks for pointing it out though :-)